# Empty Dock settings in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: system-settings, ubuntu-dock, gnome-control-center, 19.04

I am getting dock settings empty as shown. Please suggest a fix. Thanks.I have updated from 18.10 to 19.04

[image]